# Alt + Tab - selected application hard to see 20.04.4 LTS

Tags: colors, application-switcher

When using alt+tab or system+tab, I see icons of active applications. (Nearly, image with gimp, key printscreen don't work during alt+tab.) [icons, selected icon with dark grey background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eV76d.png) Selected icon is marked with dark grey background, but hardly to see against black background of other icons. I want to adjust this color, example: [icons, selected icon with green background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM5o9.png). Gnome themes seem not to touch this appearence. I use fresh install of ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, gnome 3.36.8. Similiar question was asked concerning ubuntu 14 and earlier, but the answers no longer work.

Comment: Answers for Ubuntu 14.04 couldn't work because it used Unity (based on Gnome but not Gnome) whereas the current releases use a slightly modified Gnome. That said, Ubuntu 20.04 with the default theme works fine and even on your own example it's perfectly visible.

Comment: Hi ChanganAuto, you seem to know a lot about it. The window switcher - or application switcher - is/are it standalone executables, and what's path & name?
By the way, it's not perfect visible. It's just to recognize by night. With full sunlight outside the windows, it just disappears.

Comment: I'm surprised there aren't more people complaining about this.  Even with 22.04 LTS the issue persists, and makes switching kind of a guessing game.

Comment: I can only second this - very hard to see when you have a little sunlight. I am surprised Accesibility - high contrast does not adjust this?